# Adding a checkbox-column to a WPF-datagrid which is linked to a datatable

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

I have a problem adding a checkbox-column to a WPF-datagrid.

1. I create a datatable with 8 columns and fill it using sql.
2. I bind the datatable to the WPF-datagrid using ItemsSource like:

   XAML:

   `<DataGrid x:Name="dgOPListEntries" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"></DataGrid>`

   CodeBehind:

   `dgOPListEntries.ItemsSource = dtOPListEntries.DefaultView;`

So far, this works fine.

I now want to add a checkbox-column to the datagrid where I can select some rows.
(The selected rows will then be updated on the sql server.)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is just to select some rows, you can use `DataGrid.SelectionMode` and `DataGrid.SelectionUnit` properties set to `DataGridSelectionMode.Extended` and `DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow`, respectively.

In addition, `DataGrid` creates checkbox column automatically for data of type `bool`, if you can add a field to your items source.